# Set OpenGL background color with lighting enabled

Tags: opengl, lighting

I want to set a background color for my OpenGL canvas.
Ususally, I use the glClearColor method and then gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
It worked fine until I needed to enable lighting.
The background color is still working, but all my textures and vertex are white.

Comment: The clear color has nothing to do with the lighting, so there must be something else wrong.

Comment: I forgot to say that when I commented the glClearColor method (or gave it 0,0,0 as parameters) I was able to see my texture.

Comment: show the relevant parts of your code. It is totally unclear what is going on.

Comment: @Karim: Clear color and primitive rasterization don't influence each other. However you might run into a problem with blending if the destination alpha is used for source fragment modulation.